# Is the NIH solely federal or public-private?

Tags: united-states, healthcare, science, hhs

Many say the US drug industry came from the Federal, not the private sector. The US invests absurdly in basic health research. There they have the National Institutes of Health, the largest health research institution in the world, which is "federal".

I know that certain (or most) research receives investment from the private sector, but I'm not sure if that makes it public-private or completely federal

I think it's both... a federal institution doesn't stop being federal because it has public-private relations, if that was [NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/directorates/spacetech/solicitations/tipping_points#:%7E:text=The%20public-private%20partnerships%20established,%2C%20and%20American%20taxpayers%2C%20money.) would be and even the [FBI](https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/news/252458986/FBI-director-calls-for-public-private-cybersecurity-partnerships) would be; because all these institutions that I mentioned have public-private partnerships

Of course in the US I don't know what they define as a public-private company or institution to compare with Brazil, but I left the link highlighted, which is from a US government website, they referred to the NIH as a federal institution: https://www.usa.gov/federal-agencies/national-institutes-of-health

Comment: Are you asking specifically about research that takes place in NIH run labs, or all research funded primarily by NIH grants (which is pretty much all biology research in the US)?

Comment: @divibisan I mean in a general sense (if NIH is public-private). I don't know what happens to NIH other than investments by private companies, along with some partnerships with private companies as well.

Comment: NIH has done several public-private partnerships for research, and I think it still has partnerships https://commonfund.nih.gov/publicprivate

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Read my point above... I want to know if it's federal, public-private, or both. I used some institutions as an example

Comment: The question is ambiguous without clarifying the purpose for which you want to know about the distinction. For tax purposes? For patent ownership purposes? To determine how influences decision making there? And so on. A determination for one purpose isn't necessarily true for all purposes.

Answer (score 4):

The NIH does not take private money, it is [funded](https://www.nih.gov/about-nih/what-we-do/budget) by Congress.

> The NIH invests about $41.7* billion annually in medical research for the American people.

It funds a lot of scientific research at the country's universities and within NIH.

> More than 80 percent of NIH’s funding is awarded for extramural research, largely through almost 50,000 competitive grants to more than 300,000 researchers at more than 2,500 universities, medical schools, and other research institutions in every state.
>
> About 10% of the NIH's budget supports projects conducted by nearly 6,000 scientists in its own laboratories, most of which are on the NIH campus in Bethesda, Maryland.

NIH *does* fund private, for-profit labs (see [here](https://report.nih.gov/award/index.cfm), and select *Domestic For-Profits*), to the tune of $2.8B out of $34B total (8%). **So, in essence, you have the relationship backward, NIH funds for-profit labs, but no one would consider it a public-private partnership**, it is a [federal agency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Institutes_of_Health).

However, its impact on private industry is understated by the $2.8B number. Companies use NIH-funded basic research to create drugs (this is, in some sense, why this system exists).

> Something odd happened when the Trump administration submitted the original version of its latest pro-corporate budget: Big Pharma didn’t like it. ... Their business models depend on Washington subsidizing expensive, high-risk basic research, mostly through the vast laboratory network funded by the NIH.
>
> The authors found that each of the 210 medicines [FDA] approved for market came out of research supported by the NIH. Of the $100 billion it spent nationally during this period, more than half of it — $64 billion — ended up helping the development of 84 first-in-class drugs. ... But the NIH doesn’t get to use the profits from these drugs to fund more research, the way it might under a model based on developing needed drugs and curing the sick, as opposed to serving Wall Street. ([Link](https://other98.com/taxpayers-fund-pharma-research-development/))